# What is a good way to output why an object won't go through all of the "if" statements?

Tags: java

I am making a program that checks to see if an elements positive and negative charges are able to combine to make 0. A thing i want to do is output the reasons why the two elements are not able to combine. But it is more difficult than i expected. for example if sodium were trying to combine with copernicium, it would output this:

Sodium doesn't combine with Copernicium:

Both valence charges have same polarity.

One or more elements is man-made.

but i can not think of a way to implement this into my code.

here is my code:

```
public void combine(Element element){
    if ((element.getValence() > 0 && valence < 0) || (element.getValence() < 0 && valence > 0)) { //one element needs a positive valence, and one needs a negative valence
        if (valence != 0 && element.getValence() != 0) { //checks to see if valence is not equal to 0
            if (natural == true && element.isNatural() == true) { //checks to see if both elements are natural
                for (int x = 1; x <= 4; x++) {//bruteforce the atoms to see if they both add up to 0.
                    for (int y = 1; y <= 4; y++) {
                        if ((valence * x) + (element.getValence() * y) == 0) {
                            System.out.println(name + " combines with " + element.getName() + " to form " + symbol + "" + x + "" + element.getSymbol() + "" + y);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: where is `natural` set?

Comment: natural is a private boolean that has a getter and setter. isNatural is a getter.

Comment: btw. you probably don't need those getters as you seem to be inside of `Element` either way and thus have access to the private variables.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to add `else` clauses for each `if` that return an appropriate message.

```
    if ((element.getValence() > 0 && valence < 0) || (element.getValence() < 0 && valence > 0)) { //one element needs a positive valence, and one needs a negative valence
    {
        // the inner tests
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The elements are both positive or both negative");
    }
}
```

This should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: But Samuel wants to print *all* of the reasons why the elements won't combine, not just the first one.

Comment: @LouisianaHasek Of course, but I'm not going to write all the code for him.  My example should be enough for him to figure it out (and learn something).

Comment: @JimGarrison thank you for your help, i have just tried a different way of checking and outputting them.